# MVC 3 DatePicker Validation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I have a datepicker and I want to change the error message when I enter something that is not a date.

Here is my model : (I've tried to change DataType.Date to DataType.DateTime, still not working)

```
    [Display(Name = "Date :")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage="Date non valide.")]
    public DateTime? Evaluation_AVQ { get; set; }
```

Here is my view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker();
});
</script>

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Evaluation_AVQ) 
 <br />
@Html.TextBox("Evaluation_AVQ", Model.Evaluation_AVQ == null ? "" : Model.Evaluation_AVQ.Value.ToLongDateString(), new { @class = "date" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Evaluation_AVQ)
```

So if I enter 'fwefwe' in the textbox it will show the message : The value 'fwefwe' is not valid for Date :.

How can I change this message to "Date non valide" ?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I dont think textbox outputs the full metadata for validation.

Try using textboxfor instead.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Evaluation_AVQ, new { @class = "date", Value = Model.Evaluation_AVQ == null ? "" : Model.Evaluation_AVQ.Value.ToLongDateString() })
```

Regards

Si